# Absolute positioning and auto width/height

Tags: css, position

I have multi-level dropdown menu and the last one isn't on the right place. So I gave it position:absolute with auto height and auto width. It looks good until I try to specify left or top positions. It collapses and takes width for about 15px.

Also if I try to give it position of relative then the wrapper doesn't see nested elements so it looks like it has width and height of 0px.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show the CSS. It's very hard to visualize the problem through description only.

Answer (score 0):

Show what you have so far.

Also make sure the parent of whatever you have `position: absolute` on has `position: relative` on it.

```
parent = position:relative

child = position:absolute
```

Comment: It was too easy. Thank you !:)

Comment: I did more than one change and that was one of them.

Comment: What was the solution then so others can use it. If you fund the answer I gave to be right, you should up-vote it.